# How to vary particle density based on the angle/normal of the mesh?

Tags: particles

I would like to have the density of the particle source depending on the angle/normal of the mesh.
**Basically, the steeper the angle, the less particle should appear there.**
[image: in red particles, in black the mesh]

I baked a normal map to use that for density but it doesn't do anything because it's not black and white, so I'd need a way to turn a normal map to a black and white image I imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would geometry nodes give a try:

with a node setup like this:

[image]

you can check the z-component of the normal and dependent on that value drive the density. I made a simple switch there, but of course you could tweak that with some mathematical formula as you like.

result:

[image]

"kind of" 2d result:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU ! I didn't knew of the geometry nodes feature and you saved my project !

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help